# Android String replace All does not work

Tags: java, android, regex, string, replaceall

In Android application, I am using

```
String num = "10,000,000.00";
num.replaceAll("," , "");
```

Expected: 10000000.00

But I am getting : 10 000 000.00

Works in most of the devices. Facing issue in few devices like Galaxy Core, Galaxy Grand duos, Galaxy Young, Galaxy Note II and Xperia C

Kindly help.

Comment: Strings are immutable. `replaceAll` is for regular expressions. Use `num = num.replace(",","");`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**replaceAll** method is not modifying the **num**'s value. Instead it is creating a new String object and returning it. So all you need to do is assign the value what replaceAll is returning to **num** variable.

But I think you need **replace** method to remove the , characters rather than **replaceAll** which first parameter is regex *(lets not mix the regex in this case)*.

The doc says:

```
replace(CharSequence target, CharSequence replacement)
Replaces each substring of this string that matches the literal target sequence with the specified literal replacement sequence.
```

So it all goes up to this:

```
num = num.replace(",", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class DataData
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws ParseException
    {

        String num = "10,000,000.00";
        num= num.replaceAll("," , "");
        System.out.println(num);///// output 10000000.00
    }
}
```

Comment: `replaceAll` is for regular expressions. Should be using `replace`.

Comment: @khelwood both would work. Naveen, you posted the exact code what op was posted.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Yes, both would work. But one of them is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Use below java code:

```
String num = "10,000,000.00";
num.replaceAll("," , "").replaceAll("\\s+" , "");
```

replaceAll method is used for the regex

Try with replace method

```
 String num = "10,000,000.00";
 num.replace("," , "");
```